# TensorFlow mixed precision training: Conv2DBackpropFilter not using TensorCore

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gpu, half-precision-float, automatic-mixed-precision

I am using the keras mixed precision API in order to fit my networks in GPU.
Typically in my code this will look [like this](https://github.com/zaccharieramzi/fastmri-reproducible-benchmark/blob/master/fastmri_recon/training_scripts/xpdnet_train.py#L146-L151).
A MWE would be:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.mixed_precision import experimental as mixed_precision

use_mixed_precision = True

if use_mixed_precision:
  policy_type = 'mixed_float16'
else:
  policy_type = 'float32'
policy = mixed_precision.Policy(policy_type)
mixed_precision.set_policy(policy)
```

This seems to have the desired effect, as, when I train my model and profile it using the TensorBoard Callback, a large chunk of my ops are run in half precision, and some of them are using TensorCore (I have a GPU with compute capability of more than 7.0).

However, `Conv2DBackpropFilter` is not using TensorCore, even though according to the TensorBoard information it is eligible for its use.

[image: TensorCore ops]

I don't have a minimal reproducible example for the whole thing yet, and I can work on it if needed but I wanted to know first if this was an expected behaviour or if there were some know gotchas, since I couldn't find any information online.

### EDIT

I have an MRE which has a different behaviour but the same question: why is TensorCore not used (all dimensions needed are multiple of 8)?

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.mixed_precision import experimental as mixed_precision

use_mixed_precision = True

if use_mixed_precision:
    policy_type = 'mixed_float16'
else:
    policy_type = 'float32'
policy = mixed_precision.Policy(policy_type)
mixed_precision.set_policy(policy)

nf = 8
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=nf, kernel_size=3, padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=nf, kernel_size=3, padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=nf, kernel_size=3, padding='same'),
])
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='sgd')

bs = 8
inputs = tf.random.normal([bs, 32, 32, 1])
outputs = tf.random.normal([bs, 32, 32, nf])

tboard_cback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(
    profile_batch='5, 10',
    log_dir='logs',
    histogram_freq=0,
    write_graph=False,
    write_images=False,
)

model.fit(inputs, outputs, callbacks=[tboard_cback], epochs=15)
```

In this MRE, 64.2% of the ops time is spent in half-precision, meaning that the half-precision is indeed happening.
In my logs I also have the check for compute capability:

```
NFO:tensorflow:Mixed precision compatibility check (mixed_float16): OK
Your GPU will likely run quickly with dtype policy mixed_float16 as it has compute capability of at least 7.0. Your GPU: Tesla V100-SXM2-32GB, compute capability 7.0
```

Yet, none of the ops (this time it's not just `Conv2DBackpropFilter`) run with TensorCore. I don't understand why.

[image: tensorcore_for_mre]

Comment: Hard to know without a MRE, but did you check that your number of filters is the multiple of 8? (See the guide: [Ensuring GPU Tensor Cores are used](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/mixed_precision#ensuring_gpu_tensor_cores_are_used)

Comment: yes they are. Ok I am going to try to come up with a reproducible example soon.

Comment: @Lescurel I added the MRE: this time none of the ops run with TensorCore even though I set all the right dimensions to a multiple of 8, and I have the correct compute capability.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, but did you get to use mixed precision? Or any fix that you might suggest?

Comment: not so far sorry